# HTML5 video - show div at certain video time

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I'm trying to show a div at a certain time in the video playback, but the code below is not working. Can someone please tell me what would be the correct way of doing this (not using popcorn...)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element_1").hide();

    var v1 = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    v1.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    videoTime = v1.currentTime;
    });

    if(videoTime == 10){
        $("#element_1").show()
    }
});
```

Also tried this but no go...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element_1").hide(); 
document.getElementsByTagName('video').addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if(this.currentTime > 10 * 60) {
$("#element_1").show()
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element_1").hide(); 
document.getElementById('v1').addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if(this.currentTime > 10) {
$("#element_1").show()
    }
});
});
```

and

```
<video id="v1" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="needles.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="needles.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video> 
<div id="element_1">Element 1</div>
```

Comment: why I am not work for this <video id="video1" class=" video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none"  width="498" height="280" poster="img/Home.jpg" data-setup="{}" onended="showfadeIn()" onplay="hidefadeIn()">
        <source src="video/sportv5b_1_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/sportv5b_1_2.ogv" type="video/ogv">
        <source src="video/sportv5b_1_2.webm" type="video/webm">
        <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
      </video>

Comment: perhaps the space in class=" video-js vjs-default-skin"

Answer (score 0):

try this now .. i think this might work ... just added a function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element_1").hide();

    var v1 = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    v1.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    videoTime = v1.currentTime;
    show_div(videoTime) 
    });

    function show_div(videoTime)
    { 
    if(videoTime == 10){
        $("#element_1").show()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVideo = videojs('v1');
myVideo.on('timeupdate', function(show){
    console.log(myVideo.currentTime());
    if(myVideo.currentTime() > 41) {
        $("#element_1").show()
    }
});
```

check this maybe help