# video.js show div at 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video.js

I want to show a hidden div tag when a video reaches 30 seconds. I'm using video.js rather than a plain `video` tag. Can someone help me?

```
<video id="video1" class=" video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none"  width="498" height="280" poster="img/Home.jpg" data-setup="{}" onended="showfadeIn()" onplay="hidefadeIn()">
    <source src="video/sportv5b_1_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/sportv5b_1_2.ogv" type="video/ogv">
    <source src="video/sportv5b_1_2.webm" type="video/webm">
    <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
```

Comment: Your question is bit unclear, could you please edit this section: `show hidden div tag when video in second 30`, (the meaning you are trying to convey is improper/unclear) so that we can help you out properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454217/html5-video-show-div-at-certain-video-time

Comment: Given the [tag:video.js] tag I'd say this is not a duplicate of that question. Granted, that's not obvious from the question alone if you're not familiar with video.js. Rather than add an event listener to the DOM element as in the "dupe" answer, you'd need to use video.js's API - `videojs('video1').on('timeupdate', function() {...})`