# Control (show) html éléments depending on video timer countdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have html element that i want to show depending on my video timer and i don't have any idea to make it happen. Is anyone can help me through?

Comment: This question is a little vague. What exactly are you trying to do and what have you tried already?

Comment: [Using HTML5 video events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924822(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What player are you using?

For HTML5 player try this

```js
$('#videoContainer').on('timeupdate', function () {
  // Get current time and make it proper
  var currentTime = this.currentTime.toFixed(2);

  // Compare time to disired
  if (currentTime > 2.12) {  
    // Show div
    $('#box').show('slow');
  }

});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video width="300" height="150" controls="" id="videoContainer">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>

<div id="box"></div>
```

For youtube player use it's API and `getCurrentTime()` method.

Comment: I've see what i was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454217/html5-video-show-div-at-certain-video-time

Comment: Ah, yes, my fault. We can't use equality operator (`==`) in this case without `setInterval`, but other operators will do the job. See updated answer.